# Sequel unique validation across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, ruby, validation, sequel, sequel-gem

I'm trying to add a [validates_unique](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html#label-validates_unique) validation using the Sequel gem and a MySQL database.

I'd like it to fail validation if the value of `column2` matches an existing value in `column3`, so something like the following (non-working) example:

```
validates_unique(:email_address){|ds| ds.where('unconfirmed_email NOT LIKE confirmed_email')}
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b0409/22) where I've used this query for the desired results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT confirmed_email AS value FROM email_addresses
  UNION SELECT DISTINCT unconfirmed_email AS value FROM email_addresses
) AS derived
```

I'm struggling with mapping it to the sequel validation. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [custom validation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/validations_rdoc.html#label-Custom+Validations) instead of `validates_unique` resolved the issue.

```
errors.add(:unconfirmed_email, 'email in use') if email_in_use?(unconfirmed_email)
```

And a private method

```
def email_in_use?(email)
  EmailAddress.where(confirmed_email: email).first ? true : false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Index column3 and just query your table for whatever value from column2 that you're validating against. If your query produces a record then your validation should fail.